# Spring MVC with HttpPutFormContentFilter can't get RequestBody when use PUT method

Tags: spring-mvc, put

I have added the `HttpPutFormContentFilter` in `web.xml`.

Here is an action for reveiving both `GET`,`POST`,`DELETE` and `PUT` method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> proxy(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params, @RequestBody byte[] body, @RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) {
```

When I use `POST` and add the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header,I can get both the request body and request param.

When I use `PUT` and add the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header,I can get the request param,but I can't get request body!

There is any bug in the HttpPutFormContentFilter?

Comment: Do you get an error? Or is an empty byte array?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got an enpty byte array.And there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) (see chapters 1.1 and 3.1.1), when you receive a POST request and the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, that form data needs to be made available through the `HttpServletRequest#getParameterXXX()` methods. This is not true for PUT requests.

In all cases, the body of the `HttpServletRequest` is available as an `InputStream` to `Servlet` and `Filter` instances.

For POST, when Spring sees

```
@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params
```

it uses a `RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve the argument. This reads directly from the `HttpServletRequest` parameter map. When Spring sees

```
@RequestBody byte[] body
```

it uses a `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` which reads from the `HttpServletRequest` `InputStream` using a `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` to fill up a `byte[]`.

Once you've read the `HttpServletRequest` `InputStream`, you cannot re-read (in the default configuration).

For PUT, because the Servlet container doesn't store form parameters in the `HttpServletRequest` for PUT requests, Spring decided to introduce the `HttpPutFormContentFilter`. This `Filter` reads the `HttpServletRequest` body to populate its own parameter map in an `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which it hands you.

Once this is done, the request parameters are available to the `RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver`, but when the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` tries to fill up the `byte[]`, there are no bytes left in the `InputStream` so it leaves it empty.

---

One workaround is to create your own `Filter` (which must execute before the `HttpPutFormContentFilter`, so it's kind of bad practice), which wraps the `HttpServletRequest` in a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which buffers the `InputStream` in a `ByteArrayInputStream` so you can re-read it as many times as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my case,I didn't need the `@RequestParam`. So I removed the `HttpPutFormContentFilter`, and it works will.